# How do you debug missing symbols as reported by linker especially of compiler __builtin* functions?

Tags: clang, ld

I keep getting the following error from the linker:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "___clear_cache", referenced from:
```

However when I do the following,

```
#if __has_builtin(__clear_cache)
#error clear cache is defined
#endif
```

I get this confirmation:

```
/Users/myHome/Projects/proofOfConcept/coreEngine/icache.c:66:2: error: clear cache is defined
```

The code is written in standard C, and is using gnu make & clang.
Thanks.

Comment: "Built in" does not preclude the need for some compiler-specific "run-time support library" (a distinct concept from the C library which has things like malloc and printf). Under gcc for instance, there is a "libgcc". For instance, division is built in right? The / operator. But on some targets it may need a supporting function.

Comment: @Kaz I understand.  The problem is I can't figure out which library to link to.  In fact I nm'ed all *clang*.* bins and libs looking for the builtin and found none!

Comment: @Kaz i looked [here](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/Driver/ToolChains.cpp).  You will see that clang driver builds the set of rt libs that it uses during linking.  search for "Select the dynamic runtime library and the target specific static library"